# Django: Custom actions in a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-cms

Django has custom 'actions' on its ModelAdmin objects, but I can't find a similar thing for the ModelForm objects. I'm using Django-CMS, so don't seem to have easy access to the list view of objects, and it makes more sense for this action to be attached to an individual object.

Is it possible to put in custom methods in the representation of an object in the admin interface (i.e. on a ModelForm)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have instance related actions, you should write custom functions and the related urls.

Next, to make it available inside change form for a specific instance you can extend the change_form template adding cusotm button (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html in {% block breadcrumbs %})